# How to directly call the sans-serif form of pkg esint?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, math-operators

pkg `esint` have sans-serif form, but to use it seems to need to load package `sansmathfonts` first

--- Now, I don’t want to use `sansmathfonts`. for example, I only enjoy using `arev`, but the height of the integral symbols makes me feel tricky, so I consider replacing it with the sans-serif form integral symbols in `esint`

Some basic code---

```
\documentclass[12pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{arev}

\usepackage{sansmathfonts}
\usepackage{esint}

\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{align*}
& \int_0^{+\infty} \left(\left(1-\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^{-\alpha}-1\right) \diff x\\
& \int_a^b f(x)g(x)\,{\mathrm d}x
        = f(a)\int_a^\xi g(x)\,{\mathrm d}x + f(b)\int_\xi^b g(x)\diff x\\
& \left| \int_{2k\pi}^{(2k+1)\pi} t^{p-2}\sin t \diff t \right|
          \ge (2k\pi)^{p-2} \int_0^{\pi} \sin t \diff t \ge 2\\
& \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\cos ax - \cos bx}{x}\diff x
\end{align*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Looking at the source, `esint` doesn’t appear to require `sansmathfonts`. What problem are you getting when you don’t load `sansmathfonts`?

Comment: Does loading `sansmathfonts` followed by `arev` followed by `esint` work?

Comment: Another possibility: Does `\usepackage{unicode-math}` and then `\setmainfont{Fira Sans}[Scale=1.0]`, `\setmathfont{Fira Math}[Scale=MatchLowercase]` work for you?

Comment: You claim, "pkg `esint` have sans-serif form". Please clarify this claim. From my understanding, the package offers only one form of the various integral symbols; it does *not* appear to provide separate serif and sans-serif versions.

Comment: @Mico It does have a sans serif version with the name "ssesint"

Comment: @Davislor tks for you commont, my problem  is that the sans form of ```esint``` needs another pkg (```sansmathfonts```) to elicit, now I directly set "ssesint" not through ```sansmathfonts```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it myself, and achieved the desired effect

```
\documentclass[12pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{arev}

\usepackage{esint}
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbolsA}{U}{ssesint}{m}{n}

\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{align*}
& \int_0^{+\infty} \left(\left(1-\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^{-\alpha}-1\right) \diff x\\
& \int_a^b f(x)g(x) \diff x
        = f(a)\int_a^\xi g(x) \diff x + f(b)\int_\xi^b g(x)\diff x\\
& \left| \int_{2k\pi}^{(2k+1)\pi} t^{p-2}\sin t \diff t \right|
\ge (2k\pi)^{p-2} \int_0^{\pi} \sin t \diff t \ge 2\\
& \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\cos ax - \cos bx}{x}\diff x
\end{align*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

`arev` just a choice, you can use other fonts to match, like

```
\usepackage[notext,sfmath]{kpfonts}
\usepackage{MdSymbol}
\usepackage{esint}
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbolsA}{U}{ssesint}{m}{n}
```